# Dialogflow intent detect language

Tags: dialogflow-es

My Dialogflow agent is in Spanish. I want to create an intent for the case of detecting a phrase in English.
Dialogflow provides the Entity @sys-language but there isn't much information about it and how it works. How can I detect in one intent all the user inputs in other language?

Answer (score 0):

In that situation you will need to use [Multilingual agents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-multilingual). You would need to use spanish language as default and add english as an additional language. Please keep in mind that you would need also configure [Language-specific data](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-multilingual#lang-specific):

> However, text used to interact with an end-user is language-specific. When building a multilingual agent, you must supply this language-specific data for each language. When you select a language from the console or provide a language to the API, you can access this language-specific data for the given language.

I would also advise you to check Romin Irani’s Blog - [Developing a multilingual Agent in Dialogflow](https://rominirani.com/writing-in-a-multilingual-agent-in-dialogflow-6ff9a43b9839). It's a well described tutorial with examples.

As information provided is quite limited (lack of process overview, expectations etc), you could also read about the [Mega Agent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-mega).

Just as an addition, you can use [Dialogflow simulator](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/console#simulator)